# Compare arrays and assigning values Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variable-assignment, jagged-arrays

I have two calendars, one for 10 cars, second for 15 drivers. I want to assign drivers to each day of cars calendar.

[Here is image of cars calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIvba.png)

[And here is imade of drivers calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56fXa.png)

Here is my code, which explane my goal, but of course doesn't work because I'm not familiar with vba I can figure out how to comparce values of both arrays by column, but can't assign value from drivers names column to cars calendar

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cars() As Variant
Dim drivers() As Variant
cars = Range("A1:F10")
drivers = Range("M1:R15")

For Each carDay In cars
   For Eeach driverDay In drivers
      Dim driver As Long
      Set driver = driverDay(1)
         If carDay(2) = driverDay(2) Then
            carDay.Value = driver
            driverDay.Value = "used"
         End If
   Next driverDay
Next carDay


End Sub
```

Comment: Your calendar pictures don't have headers... complicates things to understand what your calendars actually contain... and it is also not clear how you want to hook up the two calendars to eachother..

Comment: Startin point seems to be you Cars Calendar that has Cars and their Bookings perhaps..? Then are you trying to assign Drivers to the Cars and have all the dates copied over into Driver Calendar?

Comment: If your code doesn't work, then if someone tries to get an explanation from it, it will draw wrong conclusions, isn't that so...? You need to put down some examples including chain of data what is given then where it goes to do what, and what that should result in... Then some code may come out of it at the end...

Comment: `cars = Range("A1:F10")` and `drivers = Range("M1:R15")` should be referenced to a Worksheet and perhaps a workbook, like `cars = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F10")` and `drivers = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("M1:R15")` as a minimum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Collection Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim coA As New Collection, coI As New Collection, coY As New Collection
    Dim n As Integer, d As Integer, sDriver As String, sCar As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For d = 1 To 5
        For n = 1 To 15
            sDriver = ws.Cells(n, "M")
            Select Case ws.Cells(n, "M").Offset(0, d)
                Case "A": coA.Add sDriver
                Case "I": coI.Add sDriver
                Case "Y": coY.Add sDriver
            End Select
        Next

        For n = 1 To 10
            sCar = ws.Cells(n, "A")
            Select Case ws.Cells(n, "A").Offset(0, d)
                Case "A": sDriver = coA(1): coA.Remove 1
                Case "I": sDriver = coI(1): coI.Remove 1
                Case "Y": sDriver = coY(1): coY.Remove 1
            End Select
            ws.Cells(20 + n, "A").Offset(0, d) = sCar & ":" & sDriver
        Next

        Set coA = Nothing
        Set coI = Nothing
        Set coY = Nothing

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I need. I seen my way with jagged arrays, but collections also work.